# Mitov AudioLab - How to capture system's default audio output device?

Tags: delphi, mitov-audio-lab

I recently installed the [AudioLab library for Delphi from Mitov software](https://www.mitov.com/html/audiolab.html). My goal is to create an audio meter / spectrum analyzer for whatever audio is being played through the system's default audio output device.

While I have successfully figured out how to capture an audio **INPUT** device (such as a microphone) using the `TALAudioIn` component, I cannot figure out how to capture an audio **OUTPUT** device. This component only accepts input devices, and I cannot find another component that captures output devices.

The only work-around I've found is to set up `Stero Mix` on my system, which relays the output to a virtual input device. However this is a dirty hack, and may not even be possible on some systems.

NOTE: This library DOES have a `TALAudioOut` component, however this only **OUTPUTS** audio to the output device, and doesn't capture it. I cannot assign it as an **INPUT**.

How do I capture the system's default audio **OUTPUT** as an **INPUT** using this AudioLab library?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at the TALASIOAudioDevice class. It's used to access system devices for both input and output.

Comment: I'm still unable to select it as an "input" for the volume meter component.

Comment: Try: ASIO -> Mixer -> VUMeter  You may need to install the ASIO driver: ASIO4ALL.org. I'm running Delphi inside of a VM and all I see is two microphones. But the sound system stuff locks my VM up. :(

Comment: It may be the ASIO driver that's locking things up. I don't work with Windows audio much any more. Do you have OpenWire installed? It gives you a GUI where you can connect components with virtual wires. For these components, you sometimes need a buffer, like mixer, amp, or something between them.

Comment: Grrrrr .... the sound system is crashing the VM, not ASIO.

Comment: Unfortunately, I got word from the author Boian Mitov himself, and he says that he does not know how to capture audio output :-/

Comment: Ok, good to know. That's odd because I'm using a Zoom LiveTrak L-8 mixer that has a USB connection; they have a device driver for it, and Zoom lets me select from that to other software, including from the "system default". So you know it must be possible. FWIW, I've been working with Web Audio API lately. It's conceptually similar to Boian's stuff, but a lot more widely used. Some good books on it have been published. But it works inside of the browser. I'm working with TMS Software's WEB Core system in Delphi to build a web app, and it works great. Something to consider.